# Django Crispy forms "add new thing" button for field

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I'm making a form using crispy forms, and I'm wondering if they is a way of adding an add button next to a field, similar to what django-admin does. I currently have a drop down list which requires something to be in it, and if it is empty, I want to be able to open up another form to add that element.

edit:

In forms.py

```
class CourseUserForm(BaseForm):
organisers = UserFullnameChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(), label=_(u'Organisers'))
userlist = TypedModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=UserList.objects.all(), label=_(u'Group'), required=False)
helper = FormHelper()
helper.layout = Layout(
    'title',
    'description',
    'organisers',
    'events',
    'userlist',
    FormActions(
        Submit('submit', (_(u'Save'))
               )
    )
)

class Meta(BaseForm.Meta):
    model = Course
    fields = ['title', 'description', 'organisers', 'events', 'userlist']
```

and in models.py

```
class Course(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_('Title'))
description = NoInitSimpleMdeField(verbose_name=_('Description'))
events = models.ManyToManyField(Event)
organisers = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', related_name='course_organiser', verbose_name=_('Organisers'))
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_('Created Date'))
```

In views.py I am using the django views generic CreateView mixin. My template is essentially consists of {% crispy form %} and some supporting css etc...

I want to add an add button next to the event field, which will open up an event add dialog. Once(/if) an event has been added, I would like the new record to appear in the drop down list.

Edit 2:

Soo my form is using the Crispy Forms Helper, and I know that I can add buttons to crispy forms, but somehow I need to allow that to open up my other form (preferably in a modal dialog box), allow it to refresh my data when its been added, and to have it set out so that the button is next to the multiple choice field. See [this](https://carolhsu.gitbooks.io/django-girls-tutorial-traditional-chiness/content/django_admin/images/edit_post3.png) example of it in django admin (The add button next to the A

Comment: can you please post your code

Comment: This has nothing to do with crispy ;) I would suggest to edit the question and put some code here. You are asking for two different things here. 1.Add field button 2. Add fields if form is empty. There are two solutions for that.

Comment: done - I don't need to add fields, just to be able to add a new record, which then displays in the field. Sorry if I wasn't clear. Also it shouldn't matter too much if it is empty or not - I want the option to be there regardless

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? This is exactly why I need.